# Advice: Struggling with Model-View-Controller in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, model

I am trying to get a better understanding of MVC. I can't find too much content out there that I truly understand and can re-engineer to better understand the inner workings.

I understand that the model is the data (JavaScript with objects or something), the View is the HTML and the controller is the browser.

Is this a correct understanding? Can anyone point me to a very simple, down and dirty example of the MVC?

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC framework includes the following components:

- **Models**. Model objects are the parts of the application that implement
  the logic for the application's data domain. Often, model objects
  retrieve and store model state in a database. For example, a Product
  object might retrieve information from a database, operate on it, and
  then write updated information back to a Products table in a SQL
  Server database.In small applications, the model is often a conceptual separation
  instead of a physical one. For example, if the application only reads
  a dataset and sends it to the view, the application does not have a
  physical model layer and associated classes. In that case, the
  dataset takes on the role of a model object.
- **Views**. Views are the    components that display the application's
  user interface (UI).    Typically, this UI is created from the model
  data. An example would    be an edit view of a Products table that
  displays text boxes,    drop-down lists, and check boxes based on the
  current state of a    Product object.
- **Controllers**. Controllers are the components that handle user
  interaction, work with the model, and ultimately select a view to
  render that displays UI. In an MVC application, the view only
  displays information; the controller handles and responds to user
  input and interaction. For example, the controller handles
  query-string values, and passes these values to the model, which in
  turn might use these values to query the database.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(VS.98).aspx?ppud=4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28VS.98%29.aspx?ppud=4)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you study Backbone JS example here https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone

Backbone is the simplest Javascript MVC library(not a framework) that you can find. It clearly defines what Model (the data that is synced to REST API), View (this is kind of confusing as View plus Router in Backbone is  equal to "Controller" in MVC world), and Template (This is the "View" in MVC world. You could use Mustache JS or underscore JS or other template engines) are.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it's similar in iOS where you have UIViewController, the controller manages the view, and is not dependent on a model. A model is used as a reservoir of data that can be called and/or persistence. A controller can have access to the model when it is interfaced or needed.